# Display post as term id

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have one problem, i added taxonomy for Student list, via function do url rewrite:

```
function ex_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {

    $feed_rules = array(
        '(.+)'    =>  'index.php?student='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $wp_rewrite->rules + $feed_rules;
}
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'ex_rewrite' );
```

I can remove from browser student/jordan, and use only as Jordan, but Jordan has lessons list, and I need when click on Jordan - display Lessons list for Jordan only, and url should be jordan/lessons-list-jordan (lessons-list-jordan was added in post type: Lessons and for Lessons was added taxonomy Student list), really make this all?

Thanks